# Integral question: zeroes of the primitive.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, numerical-methods, closed-form

Let $z$ be a complex number.
Let $f(z)$ be an elementary function but not a polynomial.
Let its integral $F(z)$ be impossible to express in elementary functions.
If we define $F(z)$ as $\int$ from $A$ to $z$ (in a straight path from $A$ to $z$), how do we know if there is a finite complex $A$? What if there are multiple values where $F(z)$ = $0$; What $A$ to choose?
How to compute $A$? What $A$ makes the computation of the integral the easiest? Is it the $A$ closest to $z$?

Comment: Could you please take a little time to expand your question? Some details are unclear. For example, what is $A$, is it a complex number? When you integrate from $A$ to $z$, which path do you integrate along? Does $f$ have poles and if so, what kind? Finally, if you want to define $F$ as an integral then it's custom to use a dummy variable:

$$ \ln x := \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} \, . $$

Comment: It usually makes more sense to start with some convenient $A$ and take the antiderivative (in some neighbourhood of $A$) that is $0$ at $A$.

Comment: @Robert Israel : I think what you meant is we work with the integration constant and/or integrate f(z) + C_2 such that we can find an antiderivative at A that is 0 whereever we want (and then pick a convenient A and/or place).

Comment: @Fly by Night : i edited it slightly. Im aware of the dummy variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is an entire function that is not a polynomial and $F$ is an antiderivative of it, the little Picard theorem says $F$ takes on every complex value with at most one exception.  That exception could be $0$, in which case $F = \exp(G)$ for some entire function $G$. Offhand I couldn't think of an example of this where $f$ is  elementary but $F$ is not.